# Python Kivy, need help to understanding a strange technique. self._object.clear() etc

Tags: python, design-patterns, kivy

I feel guilty for asking question I can not properly name because I can not name the pattern used in the code.

There is a code on github I'm trying to understand and failing to do so.
[https://github.com/kivy-garden/speedmeter/blob/master/kivy_garden/speedmeter/**init**.py](https://github.com/kivy-garden/speedmeter/blob/master/kivy_garden/speedmeter/__init__.py)

Pattern I don't understand is in lines 128,129 and 181, 182 and many other places.

Big picture is.
There a class

```
class MyClassName(Widget):
```

there are methods e.g.

```
    def _draw_this_and_that(self):
       self._someName.clear()
       add = self._someName.add
       add(Color(rgba=get_color_from_hex(color)))
```

This "_someName" found in whole code only in those 2 places as my code sample.

I understand that

```
   add = self._someName.add
```

creates function "add" but why that is needed? why not calling

```
   self._someName.add
```

instead?

I guess that

```
   self._someName.clear()
```

does erase whatever was added to "_someName", right?

I completely do not understand how

```
  add(Color(rgba=get_color_from_hex(color)))
```

does it job (but it does) and then whatever is drawn will be with that color.

Do I guess it right that if I need to change color (if some condition met) then I could just add different color?

```
  add(Color(rgba=get_color_from_hex(different_color)))
```

and don't stress that adding will cause memory leak because

```
   self._someName.clear()
```

will take care of it?

I never seen such pattern. I'd be very happy if someone could explain how it works and why.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_somenameIG` are canvas instruction groups that are created in the `__init__()` method:

```
    add = self.canvas.add
    for instructionGroupName in _ig:
        ig = InstructionGroup()
        setattr(self, '_%sIG' % instructionGroupName, ig)
        add(ig)
```

So, the `self._someName.clear()` is clearing a canvas instruction group, and the `add()` method adds instructions to the group.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427969/17375573) I would like to address the following:

> Pattern I don't understand is in lines 128,129 and...

According to its [documentation](https://github.com/kivy-garden/speedmeter/blob/master/doc/source/api.rst#sectors) the attr. `sectors` in [line 130](https://github.com/kivy-garden/speedmeter/blob/d010ab8315391c5d81f85f4515d5ad3bdef0aef3/kivy_garden/speedmeter/__init__.py#L130) is a list of alternating values and colors a copy of which is stored locally by `l` and then the `color` value(s) is(are)  passed to the `InstructionGroup`. Since it is used as a redrawing mechanism, the instruction groups are removed from canvas by the method `clear` before drawing again.

> creates function "add" but why that is needed? why not calling...

This is done mainly to prevent the [re-evaluation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...) process.